# Linear regression to fit a power-law

Tags: matplotlib, linear-regression, power-law

I have two data sets `index_list` and `frequency_list` which I plot in a loglog plot by `plt.loglog(index_list, freq_list)`. Now I'm trying to fit a power law `a*x^(-b)` with linear regression. I expect the curve to follow the initial curve closely but the following code seems to output a similar curve but mirrored on the y-axis.
I suspect I am using `curve_fit` badly.

why is this curve mirrored on the x-axis and how I can get it to properly fit my inital curve?

[Using this data](https://norvig.com/google-books-common-words.txt)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

f = open ("input.txt", "r")
index_list = []
freq_list = []
index = 0
for line in f:
    split_line = line.split()
    freq_list.append(int(split_line[1]))
    index_list.append(index)
    index += 1

plt.loglog(index_list, freq_list)
def power_law(x, a, b):
    return a * np.power(x, -b)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(power_law, index_list, freq_list)
plt.plot(index_list,  power_law(freq_list, *popt))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, that unfortunately only results in a `y=x` line

Comment: @JohanC I have edited the post to include sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below made the following changes:

- For the scipy functions to work, it is best that both `index_list` and `freq_list` are numpy arrays, not Python lists. Also, for the `power` not to overflow too rapidly, these arrays should be of `float` type (not of `int`).
- As `0` to a negative power causes a divide-by-zero problem, it makes sense to start the `index_list` with `1`.
- Due to the powers, also for floats an overflow can be generated. Therefore, it makes sense to add bounds to `curve_fit`. Especially `b` should be limited not to cross about 50 (the highest value is about `power(100000, b) giving an overflow when` b`e.g. is`100`)`. Also setting initial values helps to direct the fitting process (`p0=...`).
- Drawing a plot with `index_list` as `x` and `power_law(freq_list, ...)` as `y` would generate a very weird curve. It is necessary that the same `x` is used for the plot and for the function.

Note that calling `plt.loglog()` changes both axes of the plot to logarithmic. All subsequent plots on the same axes will continue to use the logarithmic scale.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def power_law(x, a, b):
    return a * np.power(x, -b)

df = pd.read_csv("https://norvig.com/google-books-common-words.txt", delim_whitespace=True, header=None)

index_list = df.index.to_numpy(dtype=float) + 1
freq_list = df[1].to_numpy(dtype=float)

plt.loglog(index_list, freq_list, label='given data')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(power_law, index_list, freq_list, p0=[1, 1], bounds=[[1e-3, 1e-3], [1e20, 50]])

plt.plot(index_list, power_law(index_list, *popt), label='power law')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]